AWS Lambda. Returning Empty Response
I'm following a tutorial for putting info into a DynamoDB and after initializing a variable the code returns an empty response and I can't seem to figure out how it makes sense at all. Code is in JavaScript
import { DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand, PutItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { marshall } from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb";

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const cognitoIdentityProviderClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient( { region: process.env.REGION } );
  const dynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient( { region: process.env.REGION } );

  try{
    const adminGetUserInput = {
      Username: event.username, 
      UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID
    };

    const adminGetUserCommand = new AdminGetUserCommand(adminGetUserInput);
    const adminGetUserResponse = await cognitoIdentityProviderClient.send(adminGetUserCommand);

    const sub = adminGetUserResponse.UserAttributes.find(attribute => attribute.Name === "sub").Value;
    const email = adminGetUserResponse.UserAttributes.find(attribute => attribute.Name === "email").Value;

    const getItemInput = {
      TableName: "Players",
      Key: marshall({ databaseid: sub })
    };

    const getItemCommand = new GetItemCommand(getItemInput);
    let statsFromDB = await dynamoDBClient.send(getItemCommand);

    const eventMatchStats = event.matchStats;

    for (const key in eventMatchStats) {
      if (statsFromDB[key] !== undefined){
        statsFromDB[key] += eventMatchStats[key];
      } else{
        statsFromDB[key] = eventMatchStats[key];
      }
    }

    const putItemInput = {
      TableName: "Players",
      Item: marshall( { ...statsFromDB } )
    };

    const putItemCommand = new PutItemCommand(putItemInput);
    const putItemResponse = await dynamoDBClient.send(putItemCommand);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: `Updated match stats for ${event.username}`
    };

  } catch(error){
    return error;
  }
};```


Status: Succeeded
Test Event Name: testRecordMatchStats
Response:
{}
Function Logs:
START RequestId: 382102d2-599c-4e65-bc47-7cb94c9ed356 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 382102d2-599c-4e65-bc47-7cb94c9ed356
REPORT RequestId: 382102d2-599c-4e65-bc47-7cb94c9ed356  Duration: 698.78 ms Billed Duration: 699 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 105 MB
Request ID: 382102d2-599c-4e65-bc47-7cb94c9ed356```
This is what I end up getting with the current code but if I put the return above the
const putItemInput = {
  TableName: "Players",
  Item: marshall( { ...statsFromDB } )
};

it outputs correctly.

Add some logging into your code, including in the catch arm. Review the logs.

What if you return valid JSON?
